# db-migrate ObjectId Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using db-migrate
https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I am trying to insert documents into a MongoDB collection and I need `ObjectId` on a few fields. I am getting an error that ObjectId is not defined

```
[ERROR] AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: ifError got unwanted exception: ObjectId is not defined
```

Does db-migrate not allow to require ObjectId?

```
  var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my require statement to

`var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;`